# How can I disable button click in if Condition. The below code doesnt work. it stop the application

Tags: android

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.next:

                count++;
                image1.setImageResource(firstArray[count]);
                image2.setImageResource(secondArray[count]);
                image3.setImageResource(thirdArray[count]);


                first.setText(first_tv[count]);

                if (count == 0){
                   forward.setClickable(false);
                   forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                    forward.setEnabled(false);

                }
```

Comment: Add logs from logcat

Comment: what is forward ? please share more code related to it

Answer (score 0):

In your ButtonClick,

```
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.next:
        count++;
        image1.setImageResource(firstArray[count]);
        image2.setImageResource(secondArray[count]);
        image3.setImageResource(thirdArray[count]);
        first.setText(first_tv[count]);

        if (count == 0){
           forward.setEnabled(false);
        }
        break;
```

also, check if your buttonclick for next is working.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this. `button.setOnClickListener(null);` will remove any listener and to set it again assign it using `button.setOnClickListener(click);`

```
View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
   if(someCondition){
       //do something 
       button.setOnClickListener(null);
    }else{
       //do something
       button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
 }
};
//some code and then
button.setOnClickListener(click);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the default value of count? if count = -1;

```
 int count = -1; 
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.next:

                count++;
                image1.setImageResource(firstArray[count]);
                image2.setImageResource(secondArray[count]);
                image3.setImageResource(thirdArray[count]);


                first.setText(first_tv[count]);

                if (count == 0){
            //       forward.setVisibility(View.GONE); // for Hide the button
                   forward.setEnabled(false); // for not clickable 

                }
```

if count = 0;

```
int count = 0; 
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.next:
if (count == 0){

                         //       forward.setVisibility(View.GONE); // for Hide the button
                   forward.setEnabled(false); // for not clickable

                    }

                    count++;
                    image1.setImageResource(firstArray[count]);
                    image2.setImageResource(secondArray[count]);
                    image3.setImageResource(thirdArray[count]);


                    first.setText(first_tv[count]);
```